# Infopath 2013 Reapeating table Rules issue

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules

I have Office Professional Plus 2013 with InfoPath 2013. I am trying to set a rule in repeating table properties but rules button is disable.

Any idea why I cannot set rules?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the Repeating Table.
2. From Ribbon, goto `Home` > `Manage Rules`

From there you can apply rules to the repeating table.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Kamal, I have already tried that. Rule does not work. If I do add rules no menu option appears. The control rules for some reason disable. Not sure why?

Comment: What operation you actually want to perform?

Comment: I want to populate repeating table from a dropdown option. If I choose one of the option from dropdown If this field changes then set a value.

Comment: How many field are in repeating table? Do you want to fill repraring table data from some other sharepoint list??